# SQL statement update record not working

Tags: php, mysqli

This SQL statement works in PHPMyAdmin but not on my website:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,
"UPDATE details INNER JOIN date ON date.dateID = details.dateID
SET details.year = '$year', details.description = '$description', details.dateID = '$decade'
WHERE id='$recordID';")
or die('Query error. try again: '.mysqli_error());
```

Although this SQL statement works when i replace it with:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE details SET year = '$year', description = '$description' WHERE id='$recordID'") or die('Query error. try again: '.mysqli_error());
```

What is happening here?  Why is the first code not updating my record?

the url is receiving the new values but it isn't updating my database.

Comment: try to write mysqli_error($con). you will get the error what you are doing. hit a try for this. and tell what mistake you did.

Comment: Why are you including a JOIN in your UPDATE statement? Especially since you don't seem to use any of the fields from the date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can update multiple tables in one `UPDATE` [query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), using `INNER JOIN` is not a correct syntax. Look like you only need to update 1 table `details`, so you don't need `INNER JOIN date ON date.dateID = details.dateID`

Comment: I never thought about that! I am new to SQL, i thought because date.ID was in both tables i would need to reference both.  Stupid mistake i have spent hours trying to fix and it was so simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the query this way...

```
UPDATE details A, date B SET
    A.year = '$year'
    , A.description = '$description'
    , A.dateID = '$decade'
WHERE A.dateID = B.dateID
    AND A.id = '$recordID'
```

...you can see that you're actually updating the value that you are joining on, which won't work.  Not knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish, I can't tell you more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it.

```
UPDATE details
SET details.year = '$year', details.description = '$description', details.dateID = '$decade'
FROM details 
INNER JOIN date ON date.dateID = details.dateID
WHERE <tableName>.id='$recordID'
```